# How to assign variables to each number from an input from the user?

Tags: c, scanf

Newbie here, and I want to ask this question. If I have a string, how do I assign many variables corresponding to each number in that string? ( c language)

For example, my string is "12345", how do I assign a = 1; b= 2; c =3; d = 4; e =5? considering that "12345" is a one-time input and not separately. Thanks

Comment: You would often use an array of values, not a separate variable for each. But you already have that array as your input. The first value is at `input[0]` with a numeric value of `input[0] - '0'`, the second value is at `input[1]` with a numeric value of `input[1] - '0'`  and so on.

Comment: Are you talking about assigning each *character* ('1', '2', ...) or converting the input to digits (numbers: 1, 2, ...)? Regardless, you start by reading your string from the user, then you would create a loop indexing each character and, as Weather Vane already indicated, assign it to an array element (converting to a number first if necessary). But the input is already an array of characters, so perhaps that's redundant. it depends upon what you're really trying to do here in the grand scheme of things. If you really do require discrete variable names, then it's discretely one at a time...

Comment: What should happen if the input is "123". What should go in `d` and in `e`?

Answer (score 0):

As  Weather Vane said we can use array to store the string and using loop we can assign each character to the variable. But problem is that how many variable we need is not fixed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char inp[10];
    int a,b,c,d,e,i;
    printf("Enter the string");
    scanf("%s",&inp);
    printf("Entered string: %s\n",inp);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            a=inp[i];
            printf("a=%c ",a);
        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            b=inp[i];
            printf("b=%c ",b);
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            c=inp[i];
            printf("c=%c ",c);
        }
        else if(i==3)
        {
             d=inp[i];
             printf("d=%c ",d);
        }
        else if(i==4)
        {
             e=inp[i];
             printf("e=%c ",e);
        }
}
printf("\n");
}
```